# Trying to assign names to dictionary, python thinks I'm indexing a string

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

This may be a stupid error on my part, and I did actually check the suggested answers before posting, but I am having trouble with the following code:

```
label_dict = {}
labels_list = [('name', 'Enter the name of the Item:'), ('price', 'Enter Price:'), ('quantity', 'Enter Quantity:'), ('date_incoming', 'Enter Date Incoming:'),
               ('date_sold', 'Enter Date Sold:'), ('location', 'Enter Location:'), ('returnable', 'Enter whether Returnable:')]

x = 0
for label_name, label_text in labels_list:
    label_dict[label_name] = Label(root, text=label_text)
    label_text[label_name].grid(row=x, column=0)
    x += 1
```

I was under the impression that I was able to create an empty dictionary and then assign values to it at a later date. But python keeps telling me that 'string indices must be integers'.

What am I doing wrong? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's typo. But the problem is in this line:

```
label_text[label_name].grid(row=x, column=0)
```

`label_text` is a string and indeed its indexes can only be integers, but you use another string as an index.

Comment: @MichaelTracey, You're welcome. If the question is answered accept anyone's answer to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Python is absolutely correct. You just have a typo and use string instead of dictionary. Instead of

```
#     vvvv
label_text[label_name].grid(row=x, column=0)
#     ^^^^
```

Use `label_dict[label_name].grid(row=x, column=0)`